# Passing arguments to nested directives in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass arguments from a parent directive to a child directive but the arguments seem to be undefined. Is there a right way to do this?

```
}).directive('flipper', function ($timeout) {
return {
    template: '<div class="flipper" ng-class="{big: big}"><div class="inner animated " ng-style="rotatorTop()"><ul><li ng-repeat="app in apps">{{app.name}}</li></ul></div></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        apps: "=",
        big: "=",
        sizes: "="
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        // undefined!
        alert($scope.apps);
        ...


    }
};
}).directive('slogan', function ($window) {
return {
    template: '<div class="message"><div class="message-big"><div class="black">{{lines[0]}}<flipper apps="apps" class="big" sizes="flipperSize"></flipper>' +
    '</div><div class="black">{{lines[1]}}</div><div class="black">{{lines[2]}}</div></div></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        apps: "=",
        lines: "="
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
          ...
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Where is the code invoking the slogan directive? My guess is simply that apps is, indeed, undefined in that code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. As your code is quite incomplete, I've made [this simple directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/V6arHP?p=preview) to demonstrate how you can pass values from the controller to a parent directive and a child directive.

```
myApp.directive('cdParent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    template: "<div cd-child option=\"option\" text=\"text\">",
    scope: {
      option: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log("inside parent directive: " + scope.option); // will log the color for the controller
      scope.text = "Hello nested directives";
    }
  }
});

myApp.directive('cdChild', function() { 
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    template: "<pre style=\"color: {{option}}\">{{text}} ({{option}})</pre>",
    scope: {
      option: "=",
      text: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log("inside child directive: " + scope.option);
    }
  }
});
```

also, the `link` function doesn't do dependency injection as a controller does, so it's arguments should be `scope, element, attrs` not `$scope, $element, $attrs`, argument order makes a difference here